# Is there a way to use Intent to change the color of a text?

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, colors

So I am using intent to pass a text from one activity to another but I need the text to go into the next activity in the color red. Is this possible to do so?

Main Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainMenu.class);
                intent.putExtra("Welcome", userET);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Menu Activity:

```
Welcometxt.setText("Welcome " + getIntent().getStringExtra("Welcome"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 Welcometxt.setText("Welcome ");
 Welcometxt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(getIntent().getStringExtra("Welcome")));
```

Comment: I was hoping to do it from my main activity where my Welcometxt isnt located. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think it would work in main if Welcomtxt is in the menu activity

Comment: Yeah i thought that might've been the case. Thanks